# Should I install node.js on Ubuntu using package manager or from source?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, package-managers

Does anyone know if installing the latest build from source is a risky route to take?  Should i just stick with the package manager?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Current recommendations

- Use [install-node-on-linux](https://github.com/dweldon/install-node-on-linux) if you want a really simple install with your user account (disclaimer: I'm the author).
- Use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) if you want to install with your user account + you need to regularly switch between versions, and you're cool with a little bit of tool and environment complexity.
- Follow the directions [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) to install via the NodeSource PPA. This is easy to do but it's the least flexible.

---

## Old Answer

**Note:** At the time of this writing I'm using Ubuntu 12.10.

There are a lot of ways to install node. I personally prefer to download the source of the latest stable build and just install it to `~/local` (you do this by adding `--prefix` to the `./configure` command as seen [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation). There really isn't any 'risk' in doing this as everything gets installed in a directory which is separated from the rest of your system. You can have a look at the node recipe in my system install scripts [here](https://github.com/dweldon/setup). I regularly run my `update_node.py` script to upgrade my installation to the latest version.

Alternatively you can follow the directions [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager) to install the latest stable version via the package manager. I haven't actually done that so I can't comment on how well it works.

What I wouldn't do is install node from the ubuntu universe packages. You'll end up with a very dated version (currently 0.6.19).

**update 1/26/2013:**

If you are interested in installing node with your user (non-root) account, I highly recommend reading [this](http://tnovelli.net/blog/blog.2011-08-27.node-npm-user-install.html) blog post. I skipped the `~/.npmrc` step, but found that the `~/.node_modules` symlink step was critial for getting `require` to work properly.

**update 12/30/2014:**

I have migrated to using linux mint and doing binary node installs. If you have any interest in writing your own installation scripts, you can find my current one [here](https://github.com/dweldon/mint-setup). Specifically have a look at what I'm doing in [node.sh](https://github.com/dweldon/mint-setup/blob/master/includes/node.sh). The `execute` function is run during the first install so it does things like configure the paths in `.bashrc`. The `install` function is run by [update-node.sh](https://github.com/dweldon/mint-setup/blob/master/update-node.sh) and is used to remove an existing installation and add a new one (the latest version or one specified by the user).

**update 1/8/2016:**

I just switched over to using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). Simply install the script and then run `nvm install node` to get the latest version. This seems like an excellent way to get node installed with your user account.

Comment: Your link to the Joyent Wiki installed version 0.8.17 circa 1/20 with current stable (reported on homepage) was 0.8.18, so it's workable. Also, as the Ubuntu tutorial amends, you'll need `software-properties-common` for `add-apt-repository` to work. Tested on Ubuntu Core 12.10

Comment: I had all sorts of problems installing Canvas and other modules with npm on Ubuntu (12.4 and 12.10) after I installed nodejs and npm using the Ubuntu repos but then I did `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js` and then reinstalled node and npm and all is working well now.  I'd like to understand better what was happening, but it's working now so I'll leave it at that for now.

Comment: @ratsbane Your modules likely required a more recent version of node, npm, or both.

Answer (score 6):

another option is nvm (Node Version Manager) :  https://github.com/creationix/nvm

bonus that it lets you easily switch between versions.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I don't see any information on setting up `nvm` to make `node` accessible to the entire system, though? (e.g. installed as root)

Answer (score 1):

Although I live in an .rpm, and not .deb realm, [`fpm`](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) can do both (needs Ruby installed). I have been able to package node.js from the latest stable source without any major difficulties. In your case, the following scenario may help:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
mkdir -p /tmp/nodejs
make install DESTDIR=/tmp/nodejs
fpm -s dir -t deb -n nodejs -v 0.8.15 -p nodejs-0.8.15.deb -C /tmp/nodejs usr
```