# installing hem fails to find strata dependency

Tags: javascript, spine.js

I'm trying to install hem on Ubuntu 12.03 LTS and I get the following:

Seems like 0.16 or later is not in the registry? Puzzled..

```
sudo npm link
[sudo] password for tim: 
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/http-proxy
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/testacular
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jade
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/eco/1.1.0-rc-3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/less
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hem-less
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fast-detective
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/watch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stylus
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/strata
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/eco/1.1.0-rc-3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/eco/-/eco-1.1.0-rc-3.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/-/underscore-1.4.4.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/less
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/less/-/less-1.3.3.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fast-detective
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fast-detective/-/fast-detective-0.0.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/hem-less
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hem-less/-/hem-less-0.0.4.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist/-/optimist-0.3.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/http-proxy
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/http-proxy/-/http-proxy-0.8.7.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script/-/coffee-script-1.4.0.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/watch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/watch/-/watch-0.5.1.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/stylus
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stylus/-/stylus-0.32.0.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/strata

npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: strata@'>=0.16.1'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.8.0","0.8.1","0.8.2","0.9.0","0.9.1","0.10.0","0.10.1","0.11.0","0.12.0","0.12.1","0.12.2","0.12.3","0.12.4","0.12.5","0.13.0","0.14.0","0.15.0","0.15.1"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:488:10)
npm ERR!     at next_ (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:438:17)
npm ERR!     at next (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:415:44)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:408:5
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:147:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (/usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs.js:230:7)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/tim/work/hem/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-38-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "link"
npm ERR! cwd /home/tim/work/hem
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message No compatible version found: strata@'>=0.16.1'
npm ERR! message Valid install targets:
npm ERR! message ["0.8.0","0.8.1","0.8.2","0.9.0","0.9.1","0.10.0","0.10.1","0.11.0","0.12.0","0.12.1","0.12.2","0.12.3","0.12.4","0.12.5","0.13.0","0.14.0","0.15.0","0.15.1"]
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/-/uglify-js-1.3.4.tgz
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/tim/work/hem/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Answer (score 2):

I think those issues are mostly from strata incompatibility with older versions of node.

Don't install node from Ubuntu's package manager, which has quite an old version. Follow the instructions here: [Should I install node.js on Ubuntu using package manager or from source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845321/should-i-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-using-package-manager-or-from-source)

Next, install npm using the npm install script, not the package manager:

```
curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

Finally, I would recommend installing hem from the git repo rather than using npm. The original developer of hem isn't really supporting it anymore and a bunch of new features of hem have been developed in a separate branch, which is up to date in the git repo.

```
git clone https://github.com/spine/hem.git
cd hem
git checkout version0_2 (or version0_3)
sudo npm install -g .
```

For further reference, I wrote a [post on setting up spine, hem, and other stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425368/spine-js-hem-server-hem-build-faq-for-windows/12595619#12595619) in a Linux environment.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the latest Node.js and npm there is a ppa that works well for ubuntu https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/

Hem on npm should be okay these days so no need to use the github source unless you want some more drastic stuff in the version0_3 branch, but version0_2 branch has been merged to master and will be pruned soon so you should avoid using that going forward.